# Convert long decimal or float to varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, decimal, varchar

One of the table I'm trying to query has a field with type `decimal(38,19)`. I need to convert it to `varchar` in order for my perl DBI module to handle. How should I write the conversion in SQL to make it work? Specifically, if I run this in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
select convert(varchar, 19040220000.0000000000000000000)
```

I get:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar.

I tried to round the number first:

```
select convert(varchar, round(19040220000.0000000000000000000, 0))
```

but that doesn't seem to work either (same error message). In fact `round()` doesn't seem to have an effect on that number for some reason. What should I do? Thx.

Comment: Don't you need to set a length for the varchar, ie. use varchar(64)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify a length for your `varchar`, it defaults to **30 characters** in the case of a `CONVERT` operation.

That's not long enough to hold your 38-digit decimal. So give your `varchar` an appropriate length in the `CONVERT` statement!!

Try this:

```
select convert(varchar(40), 19040220000.0000000000000000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a varchar with a set length larger than the precision you want, i.e.

```
select convert(varchar(64), 19040220000.0000000000000000000)
```